# Export specific page for import into other pages

Tags: oracle, import, export, oracle-apex

I created a modal dialog in oracle apex. It contains regions, items, processes and a few codesnippets. It is very useful for me and it would be great if I could integrate it into other applications that I do not have to remake everything everytime I need this usefull modal dialog.

Is there a easy way to export my modal dialog and import it in other applications? I already tried to export it as ZIP-File and then load it into another application but it seems this can not be done. It says that the page can not be imported beacuse the page comes from another application.

```
This page was exported from a different application or from an application in different workspace. Page cannot be installed in this application
```

Why I exported the modal dialog as ZIP? So that I can save it in my docs and offer the download for me and my team.

Maybe there are alternative ways? Export the modal dialog completly as plugin or something else?

Best regards,
Filip.

Comment: Import isn't possible, but you can (within the page builder when editing a page), clic "create page as a copy".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The approach I am using is to manually alter the App ID in the export file to the one where I want to import the page to.

If you open the sql file one of the first statements is `wwv_flow_api.import_begin`. Change the `p_default_application_id` parameter value to the App ID you want to import into.

Afterwards you will not get the error message. Keep in mind that if the app already has a page with the same ID it will be overwritten on import.